# Export html table with dropdown lists to a CSV file using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

As written in the title , I have HTML table that has few columns where the user has to select values from dropdown lists. What I want to do is to be able to export this table to a CSV file . I found online a jquery plugin but I have a problem with the dropdown lists. It gives back all of the option for each row instead the ones that are selected. I tried fixing this but I failed.

The JQuery plugin and and example table are in the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bLa8pn74/

I tried to insert this:

```
if($(this).find('select').each(function(){
                    line.push(_quote_text($(this).find("option:selected").text()));
                }));
```

But it only printed the head row. I now it should be simple change but I just can't figure it out .

EDIT: I would like that my solution is without creating new table.

**EDIT 2**: I tried this code also :

```
if($(this).find('select')){
    line.push(_quote_text($(this).find('option:selected').text()));
            }
    line.push(_quote_text(_trim_text($(this).text())));
```

And it gives me the selected option but also afterwards all dropdown options, and extra "","", where it finds an empty cell.

And If I add "else" before the second "line.push" then it returns only the selected values and everything else is empty.

Comment: use two specular tables, the first (visible) with select and the second (hidden and without selects) updated when a select of the first table changes. so when you click on exportToCSV button you can pass the hidden table with the right values in his cells

Comment: so I should create a new table not new columns ?

Comment: Below the code to explain ad my vision works i hope this could helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what was missing. I just needed the ".length" in my if condition.

```
if($(this).find('select').length){
          line.push(_quote_text($(this).find('option:selected').text()));
 }else{
       line.push(_quote_text(_trim_text($(this).text())));
       }
```

Comment:  all you were need ,was weekend

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras hahaha yes a nice weekend did the charm. Now I can finally finish my project xD

Answer (score -1):

Here is your working Code....

```js
jQuery("#import").on('click', function (event) { 
       $('#my_id').table2csv({
        file_name:  'test.csv',
        header_body_space:  0
       });
        
    });

// JQuery Plugin 
/**
 * @description: Plugin to export HTML table to CSV file.
 * @author: VenkataRamanaB
 * @link: https://github.com/venkataramanab/table2csv
 * Feel free to use or modify this plugin as far as my full name is kept
 */

(function ($) {
    const _trim_text = (text) => {
        return text.trim();
    };
    const _quote_text = (text) => {
        return '"' + text + '"';
    };
    const _export = (lines, file_name) => {
        const uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(lines.join('\n'));
        const el_a = document.createElement('a');
        el_a.href = uri;
        el_a.download = file_name;
        document.body.appendChild(el_a);
        el_a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(el_a);
    };



    const init = (tb, options) => {
        let lines = [];
        $(tb).find('thead>tr').each(function () {
            let line = [];
            $(this).find('th').each(function () {
                line.push(_quote_text(_trim_text($(this).text())));
            });
            lines.push(line.splice(0).toString());
        })
        
        
        
        for (let i = 0; i < options.header_body_space; i++) lines.push('\n');
        $(tb).find('tbody>tr').each(function () {
            let line = [];
            $(this).find('td').each(function () {
               
              /* If <td> has <select>, CSV have selected value */
              
              if($(this).find('select').length > 0){
                var optVal = $(this).find('select').val();
                var selectVal = $(this).find('option[value="'+optVal+'"]').text();
                line.push(_quote_text(_trim_text(selectVal)));
              }
              else{
                line.push(_quote_text(_trim_text($(this).text())));
              }
                
                   
                
            });
            lines.push(line.splice(0).toString());
        })
        _export(lines, options.file_name)
    };



    $.fn.extend({
        table2csv: function (options) {
            const default_options = {
                file_name: 'table_records.csv',
                header_body_space: 1
            };
            options = $.extend(default_options, options);
            init(this, options);
        }
    })
})(jQuery);


$(function(){
 var firstDDM = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'];
  var firstshortcut = ['a','b','c','d'];
  var option = "",
    select = "";
  for(var i=0; i<firstDDM.length;i++){
   option += '<option value="'+ firstshortcut[i] + '">' + firstDDM[i] + '</option>';
  }
  select = '<select class="firstDDM" type="firstDDM">' + option + '</select>';
  
  $("tr").each(function() {
            $(this).find("td:eq(3)").append(select);
      });
});
```

```css
table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px black solid;
            font: 12px sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            table-layout:auto;
            
        }
        td {
            border: 1px black solid;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        thead:hover{
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        thead tr:first-child{
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #5bc0de;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even){
            background-color: #f2f2f2
        }
        
        tr:hover{
            background-color: #5bc0de;
        }
        button{
            display: inline;
            padding: 50px;
        }
        input button{
            display: inline;
        }
        .dropbtn{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .table-responsive {
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 800px;
        }
        .table-responsive table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .table-responsive thead th{
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #5bc0de;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 12px;
        }
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: darkgrey;
            outline: 1px solid slategrey;
        }
        .myButtons{
            display: inline;
            padding: 20px;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Filtered CSV File</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Filtered CSV FIle
    </h1>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <div>
   <input  type="button" value="Import" class="btn btn-info" id="import">
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="dataframe my_class" id="my_id">
       <thead>
         <tr style="text-align:right;">
           <th> </th>
           <th>col1</th>
           <th>col2</th>
           <th>col3</th>
           <th>col4</th>
           <th>col5</th>
           <th>col6</th>
           <th>col7</th>
           <th>col8</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
         
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th>1</th>
           <td>row1</td>
           <td>row1</td>
           <td>row1</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>row1</td>
           <td><select name="code">
                    <option value="a">AAA</option>
                    <option value="b">BBB</option>
                </select></td>
           <td>row1</td>
           <td>row1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <th>2</th>
           <td>row2</td>
           <td>row2</td>
           <td>row2</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>row2</td>
           <td><select name="code">
                    <option value="a">AAA</option>
                    <option value="b">BBB</option>
                </select></td>
           <td>row2</td>
           <td>row2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <th>3</th>
           <td>row3</td>
           <td>row3</td>
           <td>row3</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>row3</td>
           <td><select name="code">
                    <option value="a">AAA</option>
                    <option value="b">BBB</option>
                </select></td>
           <td>row3</td>
           <td>row3</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```